# why is mysql not using the right index?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a problem where the correct index is no being used.

I have the following indexes on an innodb table (about 500,000 rows) :

```
+-------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name               | Seq_in_index | Column_name            | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| osdate_user |          0 | PRIMARY                |            1 | id                     | A         |      419700 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          0 | email                  |            1 | email                  | A         |      419700 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          0 | username               |            1 | username               | A         |      419700 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | lastvisit              |            1 | lastvisit              | A         |      419700 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | active                 |            1 | active                 | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | gender                 |            1 | gender                 | A         |          88 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | regdate                |            1 | regdate                | A         |      419700 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | lastupdate             |            1 | lastupdate             | A         |      419700 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | password               |            1 | password               | A         |      419700 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | age                    |            1 | age                    | A         |         190 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | is_new                 |            1 | is_new                 | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | private_photos         |            1 | private_photos         | A         |           8 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | pictures_cnt           |            1 | pictures_cnt           | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | pictures_cnt           |            2 | private_photos         | A         |          10 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |            1 | status                 | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |            2 | active                 | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |            3 | gender                 | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |            4 | age                    | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |            5 | country                | A         |        7630 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |            6 | city                   | A         |       46633 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |            7 | pictures_cnt           | A         |       83940 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |            8 | private_photos         | A         |      139900 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |            9 | lang                   | A         |      209850 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| osdate_user |          1 | status                 |           10 | is_new                 | A         |      209850 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+-------------+------------+------------------------+--------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

This query :

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT user.id, user.active
FROM osdate_user user
WHERE user.active =1
AND user.status =  'active'
AND user.gender =  'M'
AND user.age
BETWEEN 19 
AND 35 
AND user.pictures_cnt >0
AND user.private_photos =  '0'
ORDER BY user.lastvisit DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 24
```

Displays the following plan :

```
+----+-------------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type        | possible_keys                                                | key                          | key_len | ref                       | rows  | filtered | Extra                                                                      |
+----+-------------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user    | index_merge | PRIMARY,active,gender,age,private_photos,pictures_cnt,status | gender,private_photos,active | 4,1,2   | NULL                      | 28204 |   100.00 | Using intersect(gender,private_photos,active); Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | userext | eq_ref      | userid                                                       | userid                       | 4       | db_name.user.id |     1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                                |
+----+-------------+---------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+---------------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**My question is why isn't the query using the index "status"**

When I force it to use the index "status" - it takes 0.2s, if I don't it takes 2.5s

Any help much appreciated. regards.

Comment: Probably because the optimizer has determined that it was not the best way to go for this query? Have you tried and forced its use, and compared times?

Comment: What storage engine is this table using?  How big is it?  I once had optimizer issues with a very large InnoDB table until I changed the innodb_stats_sample_pages variable from its default of 8 to 128.

Comment: I updated with info on forced index use and table info - forcing it to use the index "status" is much faster than the index(es) mysql chose

Comment: apparently (seeing `user.status =  'active'`) you should NOT use an index on this column, anyway. What are the status cardinality? 3, 4? If so, this is not recommended to set up an index on this column.

Comment: @Sebas this column is an enum. please elaborate further ?

Comment: well then it depends how big is the enum. Basically the point of an index is to help you indentify the row you wish to retrieve. If the column you're indexing has x different values, and let's say, with an equally spreaded cardinality, it means the engine (using your index) would have to parse n/x rows to get the one you need. If x is small, it becomes innefficient because the cost to access the blocks of an index is not null, and in reality it is faster to proceed a full table scan than a low card index. next comment to complete

Comment: In your case, maybe the 'active' value is used a reallllllly few times which tricks the benches for this particular case. What about doing a test with other values than "active"? Try it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit, I found some recommendations regarding not using columns that allow null in indexes. I changed the columns in the status index to all be non-null, and now that index is being used.

As is usually the case, the simplest and cleanest solutions are the best.

Answer (score 0):

u have several indexes that overlap the fields they index.
For example
`pictures_cnt` and `status`
The optimizer "sees" your query as closer to use the fields of the `pictures_cnt` rather than the `status` index. If u will have more fields in the `where` that belongs to the `status` index, it might decide to use that index instead of `picture_cnt`

Do notice, it can't use both.

If u think the optimizer is wrong (as is the case on uncommon occasions) u can force it to use the index u want it to use. do benchmark it though.

Comment: Forcing it does resolve the issue, but it's not a path i want to go down. Please note that it did not use the index pictures_cnt - it's listed only in the "possible indexes"